# Is there a way to declare a Groovy string format in a variable?

Tags: groovy

I currently have a fixed format for an asset management code, which uses the Groovy string format using the dollar sign:

```
def code = "ITN${departmentNumber}${randomString}"
```

Which will generate a code that looks like:

> ITN120AHKXNMUHKL

However, I have a new requirement that the code format must be customizable. I'd like to expose this functionality by allowing the user to set a custom format string such as:

> OCP${departmentNumber}XI${randomString}
>
> PAN-${randomString}

Which will output:

> OCP125XIBQHNKLAPICH
>
> PAN-XJKLBPPJKLXHNJ

Which Groovy will then interpret and replace with the appropriate variable value. Is this possible, or do I have to manually parse the placeholders and manually do the string.replace?

Comment: May be the question is not clear to me, but what you are asking for  can be done in Groovy. Can you try with a sample script? I think you would get your answer working on the sample.

Comment: I _think_ he wants the "user" to enter a GString, which is then evaluated.

Comment: Why not use `String.format()`, or `MessageFormat.format()` and let the user choose the pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that [GString lazy evaluation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation) fits the bill:

```
deptNum = "C001"
randomStr = "wot"

def code = "ITN${deptNum}${->randomStr}"

assert code == "ITNC001wot"

randomStr = "qwop"

assert code == "ITNC001qwop"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the original poster wants to use a variable as the format string. The answer to this is that string interpolation only works if the format is a string literal. It seems it has to be translated to more low level `String.format` code at compile time. I ended up using `sprintf`

baseUrl is a String  containing `http://example.com/foo/%s/%s` loaded from property file

```
def operation = "tickle"
def target = "dog"
def url = sprintf(baseUrl, operation, target)

url
===> http://example.com/foo/tickle/dog
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you do not need to use lazy evaluation of GString, the normal `String.format()` of java would do the trick:

```
def format = 'ITN%sX%s'
def code = { def departmentNumber, def randomString -> String.format(format, departmentNumber, randomString) }
assert code('120AHK', 'NMUHKL') == 'ITN120AHKXNMUHKL'
format = 'OCP%sXI%s'
assert code('120AHK', 'NMUHKL') == 'OCP120AHKXINMUHKL'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

for [Triple double quoted string](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_triple_double_quoted_string)

```
def password = "30+"

def authRequestBody = """
<dto:authTokenRequestDto xmlns:dto="dto.client.auth.soft.com">
   <login>support@soft.com</login>
   <password>${password}</password>
</dto:authTokenRequestDto>
"""
```